# jQuery slideUp doesn't function in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, slidetoggle, slideup

I'm building a website where I'm using jQuery to make a dynamic information part on the index page. It is working in Opera, Chrome and Firefox as you can see here (if you are browsing with one of these 3 browsers):

http://www.verhoevenkevin2011.dreamhosters.com/index.php

Just hover over the scales and you will see the effect.

However, if you are browsing with Internet Explorer, the two div's that are used for this effect are shown under each other instead of on top of eachother, like this:

http://img38.imageshack.us/content_round.php?page=done&l=img38/9358/jqsli.jpg&via=mupload

The bottom copy of the divs however does seem to work as it should. I have been looking around the internet for some help, but I'm fairly new to jQuery and don't seem to find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem with your HTML. Specifically that you're missing a closing `</div>` in -

```
<a href="#" class="toggle"><div id="register"></a>
```

IE tends to be finicky about bad syntax wheres Firefox and Chrome tend to try to interpret your code and fix it up as needed. Hope that helps!

Comment: OK, i fixed it. The div should have been outside the <a>, it does had a closing </div> though :)

Comment: Cool, looks like that fixed the issue with that `slideUp` function, although you seem to have more problems in your HTML. If, this was helpful please click upvote and accept thanks!